# Django template inception

Tags: django, templates, include

I am trying to create a file which contains a group of block tags, something like this:

```
help.html
{% block help1 %} This is help1 {% endblock %}
{% block help2 %} This is help2 {% endblock %}
```

My intent is to include this file and let it be rendered by a child template which already has an `extends` tag.

An example of the child would look something like this:

```
child.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
... some HTML ...
{% block help1 %}{% endblock %}
... some HTML ...
{% block help2 %}{% endblock %}
```

I have tried `{% include "help.html" %}`, but it render the blocks inside "help.html". However, I only want to have these blocks to be *called* in a different file, in order to have it all organized.

Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have help.html extend from base.html, and then have child.html extend from help.html. Change `{% block help1 %}{% endblock %}` to `{% block help1 %}{{ block.super }}{% endblock %}`; that way, you can put the blocks where you want, but use the block content defined in help.html.

Comment: it works perfect, but seems weird to me, it's like the file with the helps(were i want to have all the reusable and editable blocks) is between the base and child template, and not below the child template. But it works great, thanks.